# c++ Moving a temporary object prevents copy elision (fix available)clang(-Wpessimizing-move) error

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am writing cmu 15-445 projects0, when i convert 'unique_ptr' to 'shared_ptr', i got "Moving a temporary object prevents copy elision" error, here is my code.

```
Trie new_trie = Trie(std::shared_ptr<TrieNode>(std::move(root_->Clone())));
// root_->Clone() is unique_ptr<TrieNode> type
```

and here is the defination of TrieNode and Clone

```
class TrieNode {
 public:
  // Create a TrieNode with no children.
  TrieNode() = default;

  // Create a TrieNode with some children.
  explicit TrieNode(std::map<char, std::shared_ptr<const TrieNode>> children) : children_(std::move(children)) {}

  virtual ~TrieNode() = default;

  // Clone returns a copy of this TrieNode. If the TrieNode has a value, the value is copied. The return
  // type of this function is a unique_ptr to a TrieNode.
  //
  // You cannot use the copy constructor to clone the node because it doesn't know whether a `TrieNode`
  // contains a value or not.
  //
  // Note: if you want to convert `unique_ptr` into `shared_ptr`, you can use `std::shared_ptr<T>(std::move(ptr))`.
  virtual auto Clone() const -> std::unique_ptr<TrieNode> { return std::make_unique<TrieNode>(children_); }

  // A map of children, where the key is the next character in the key, and the value is the next TrieNode.
  std::map<char, std::shared_ptr<const TrieNode>> children_;

  // Indicates if the node is the terminal node.
  bool is_value_node_{false};

  // You can add additional fields and methods here. But in general, you don't need to add extra fields to
  // complete this project.
};
```

here is the error

```
Moving a temporary object prevents copy elision (fix available)clang(-Wpessimizing-move)
```

I am using clang-14 and vscode, vscode's quick fix let me delete std::move, but why?
As far as i know, unique_ptr can't be passed as a parameter directly.

Comment: at a guess `root->Clone()` returns by value, it's therefore already an `rvalue` and `std::move` is superfluous

Comment: Given the name of the function `Clone()` one has to assume that new object is returned there. In some sense this can be automatically moved, because the compiler knows the object doesn't exist in any other form.

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning that you elevated to an error with `-Werror` or something like that. The code is fine in both cases and there is no difference in performance in this case either. However the warning is correct that applying `std::move` to the return value of a function that returns by-value or by-rvalue-reference is always a pessimization at worst or a complete noop otherwise. A function call expression returning anything but a lvalue reference is already a rvalue expression and the only purpose of `std::move` is to turn an lvalue expression into a rvalue expression.